# Why am I not able to login directly using SSH

Tags: ssh, users, login

Suppose, the server address is **abcd.com**.
On my local machine at my workplace, I have to login to that server, using

```
ssh <my employeeid>@abcd.com
```

Then, to login to user **myname** , I have to use

```
su - myname
```

This way I login, but why can't I directly login to that server using

```
ssh myname@abcd.com
```

Comment: Check `/var/log/auth.log`. The user is probably not allowed to use SSH. Other ways to find more information is to make ssh more verbose with one or more -v flags or to run the daemon with a -d (debug) flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't, this means that SSH daemon configuration (on the server) forbids it. This can be done by several different settings in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`: `AllowUsers`, `AllowGroups`, `DenyGroups` and `DenyUsers`. Have a look at `man sshd_config`.

The order of interpreting those directives is also described in the manpage:

> By default, login is allowed for all groups.  The allow/deny directives are processed in the following order: DenyUsers, AllowUsers, DenyGroups, and finally AllowGroups.